# STM32F4-Discovery Board: Print out data from connected sensor on the PC screen

Tags: c, accelerometer, gyroscope, i2c, stm32f4discovery

The IDE I use is 'Keil µVision5'.

I own a STM32F429ZIT-Discovery Board (it has a LCD display on board), to which I connected a [Bosch Sensortec BNO055 9-Axis IMU](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor/overview). I want them to communicate via I²C to each other, thus I already made the required connections as follows:

- Vin (Sensor) -> 5V (Discovery Board)
- GND (Sensor) -> GND (Discovery
  Board)
- SDA (Sensor) -> PB7 (Discovery Board)
- SCL (Sensor) -> PB6
  (Discovery Board)

I downloaded the BNO055_driver, which contains the file '[bno055_support.c](https://github.com/BoschSensortec/BNO055_driver/blob/master/bno055_support.c)' (it includes code examples on how to get data from the sensor).

I find this very confusing. I don't know exactly which lines of code I need to include in my project.
I tried it, and I also included some lines that should be relevant for I²C.

I must say I am very inexperienced in programming and microcontrollers in general, clearly. And it's just like a bunch of pieces of code that I scrambled together, which probably don't make any sense. Please bear with me. Here you can see the code I tried.

The mess I've got so far:

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"                 
#include "system_stm32f4xx.h" 
#include "stm32f4xx_i2c.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include "bno055.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x29                          // BNO055 Slave Address

void init_I2C1(void){

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    I2C_InitTypeDef I2C_InitStruct;

    // enable APB1 peripheral clock for I2C1
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);
    // enable clock for SCL and SDA pins
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

    /* setup SCL and SDA pins
     * You can connect I2C1 to two different
     * pairs of pins:
     * 1. SCL on PB6 and SDA on PB7 
     * 2. SCL on PB8 and SDA on PB9
     */
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7; // we are going to use PB6 and PB7
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;           // set pins to alternate function
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;      // set GPIO speed
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD;         // set output to open drain --> the line has to be only pulled low, not driven high
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;           // enable pull up resistors
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);                 // init GPIOB

    // Connect I2C1 pins to AF  
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_I2C1); // SCL
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_I2C1); // SDA

    // configure I2C1 
    I2C_InitStruct.I2C_ClockSpeed = 100000;         // 100kHz
    I2C_InitStruct.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;         // I2C mode
    I2C_InitStruct.I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2; // 50% duty cycle --> standard
    I2C_InitStruct.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0x00;          // own address, not relevant in master mode
    I2C_InitStruct.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Disable;       // disable acknowledge when reading (can be changed later on)
    I2C_InitStruct.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit; // set address length to 7 bit addresses
    I2C_Init(I2C1, &I2C_InitStruct);                // init I2C1

    // enable I2C1
    I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);
}

/* This function issues a start condition and 
 * transmits the slave address + R/W bit
 * 
 * Parameters:
 *      I2Cx --> the I2C peripheral e.g. I2C1
 *      address --> the 7 bit slave address
 *      direction --> the tranmission direction can be:
 *                      I2C_Direction_Tranmitter for Master transmitter mode
 *                      I2C_Direction_Receiver for Master receiver
 */
void I2C_start(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx, uint8_t address, uint8_t direction){
    // wait until I2C1 is not busy anymore
    while(I2C_GetFlagStatus(I2Cx, I2C_FLAG_BUSY));

    // Send I2C1 START condition 
    I2C_GenerateSTART(I2Cx, ENABLE);

    // wait for I2C1 EV5 --> Slave has acknowledged start condition
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_MODE_SELECT));

    // Send slave Address for write 
    I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2Cx, address, direction);

    /* wait for I2C1 EV6, check if 
     * either Slave has acknowledged Master transmitter or
     * Master receiver mode, depending on the transmission
     * direction
     */ 
    if(direction == I2C_Direction_Transmitter){
        while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_TRANSMITTER_MODE_SELECTED));
    }
    else if(direction == I2C_Direction_Receiver){
        while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_RECEIVER_MODE_SELECTED));
    }
}

/* This function transmits one byte to the slave device
 * Parameters:
 *      I2Cx --> the I2C peripheral e.g. I2C1 
 *      data --> the data byte to be transmitted
 */
void I2C_write(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx, uint8_t data)
{
    I2C_SendData(I2Cx, data);
    // wait for I2C1 EV8_2 --> byte has been transmitted
    while(!I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_TRANSMITTED));
}

/* This function reads one byte from the slave device 
 * and acknowledges the byte (requests another byte)
 */
uint8_t I2C_read_ack(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx){
    // enable acknowledge of recieved data
    I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2Cx, ENABLE);
    // wait until one byte has been received
    while( !I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_RECEIVED) );
    // read data from I2C data register and return data byte
    uint8_t data = I2C_ReceiveData(I2Cx);
    return data;
}

/* This function reads one byte from the slave device
 * and doesn't acknowledge the recieved data 
 */
uint8_t I2C_read_nack(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx){
    // disabe acknowledge of received data
    // nack also generates stop condition after last byte received
    // see reference manual for more info
    I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2Cx, DISABLE);
    I2C_GenerateSTOP(I2Cx, ENABLE);
    // wait until one byte has been received
    while( !I2C_CheckEvent(I2Cx, I2C_EVENT_MASTER_BYTE_RECEIVED) );
    // read data from I2C data register and return data byte
    uint8_t data = I2C_ReceiveData(I2Cx);
    return data;
}

/* This funtion issues a stop condition and therefore
 * releases the bus
 */
void I2C_stop(I2C_TypeDef* I2Cx){
    // Send I2C1 STOP Condition 
    I2C_GenerateSTOP(I2Cx, ENABLE);
}

int main(void){

    init_I2C1(); // initialize I2C peripheral

    uint8_t received_data[2];

    while(1){

        I2C_start(I2C1, SLAVE_ADDRESS<<1, I2C_Direction_Transmitter); // start a transmission in Master transmitter mode
        I2C_write(I2C1, 0x20); // write one byte to the slave
        I2C_write(I2C1, 0x03); // write another byte to the slave
        I2C_stop(I2C1); // stop the transmission

        I2C_start(I2C1, SLAVE_ADDRESS<<1, I2C_Direction_Receiver); // start a transmission in Master receiver mode
        received_data[0] = I2C_read_ack(I2C1); // read one byte and request another byte
        received_data[1] = I2C_read_nack(I2C1); // read one byte and don't request another byte, stop transmission
    }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 *  The following functions are used for reading and writing of
 *  sensor data using I2C communication
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#ifdef  BNO055_API
/*  \Brief: The function is used as I2C bus read
 *  \Return : Status of the I2C read
 *  \param dev_addr : The device address of the sensor
 *  \param reg_addr : Address of the first register, will data is going to be read
 *  \param reg_data : This data read from the sensor, which is hold in an array
 *  \param cnt : The no of byte of data to be read
 */
s8 BNO055_I2C_bus_read(u8 dev_addr, u8 reg_addr, u8 *reg_data, u8 cnt);
/*  \Brief: The function is used as SPI bus write
 *  \Return : Status of the SPI write
 *  \param dev_addr : The device address of the sensor
 *  \param reg_addr : Address of the first register, will data is going to be written
 *  \param reg_data : It is a value hold in the array,
 *      will be used for write the value into the register
 *  \param cnt : The no of byte of data to be write
 */
s8 BNO055_I2C_bus_write(u8 dev_addr, u8 reg_addr, u8 *reg_data, u8 cnt);
/*
 * \Brief: I2C init routine
*/
s8 I2C_routine(void);
#endif
/********************End of I2C function declarations***********************/
s32 bno055_data_readout_template(void)
{
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 *********************** START INITIALIZATION ************************
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 #ifdef BNO055_API
/*  Based on the user need configure I2C interface.
 *  It is example code to explain how to use the bno055 API*/
    I2C_routine();
 #endif
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 *  This function used to assign the value/reference of
 *  the following parameters
 *  I2C address
 *  Bus Write
 *  Bus read
 *  Chip id
 *  Page id
 *  Accel revision id
 *  Mag revision id
 *  Gyro revision id
 *  Boot loader revision id
 *  Software revision id
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    comres = bno055_init(&bno055);

/*  For initializing the BNO sensor it is required to the operation mode
    of the sensor as NORMAL
    Normal mode can set from the register
    Page - page0
    register - 0x3E
    bit positions - 0 and 1*/
    power_mode = POWER_MODE_NORMAL; /* set the power mode as NORMAL*/
    comres += bno055_set_power_mode(power_mode);
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*
************************* END INITIALIZATION *************************

/************************* START READ RAW SENSOR DATA****************/

/*  Using BNO055 sensor we can read the following sensor data and
    virtual sensor data
    Sensor data:
        Accel
        Mag
        Gyro
    Virtual sensor data
        Euler
        Quaternion
        Linear acceleration
        Gravity sensor */
/*  For reading sensor raw data it is required to set the
    operation modes of the sensor
    operation mode can set from the register
    page - page0
    register - 0x3D
    bit - 0 to 3
    for sensor data read following operation mode have to set
     * SENSOR MODE
        *0x01 - OPERATION_MODE_ACCONLY
        *0x02 - OPERATION_MODE_MAGONLY
        *0x03 - OPERATION_MODE_GYRONLY
        *0x04 - OPERATION_MODE_ACCMAG
        *0x05 - OPERATION_MODE_ACCGYRO
        *0x06 - OPERATION_MODE_MAGGYRO
        *0x07 - OPERATION_MODE_AMG
        based on the user need configure the operation mode*/
    comres += bno055_set_operation_mode(OPERATION_MODE_ACCONLY);

/******************START READ CONVERTED SENSOR DATA****************/

/*  API used to read Linear acceleration data output as m/s2
    float functions also available in the BNO055 API */
    comres += bno055_convert_double_linear_accel_x_msq(&d_linear_accel_datax);
    comres += bno055_convert_double_linear_accel_y_msq(&d_linear_accel_datay);
    comres += bno055_convert_double_linear_accel_z_msq(&d_linear_accel_dataz);
    comres += bno055_convert_double_linear_accel_xyz_msq(&d_linear_accel_xyz);

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*
************************* START DE-INITIALIZATION ***********************
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  For de - initializing the BNO sensor it is required to the operation mode
    of the sensor as SUSPEND
    Suspend mode can set from the register
    Page - page0
    register - 0x3E
    bit positions - 0 and 1*/
    power_mode = POWER_MODE_SUSPEND; /* set the power mode as SUSPEND*/
    comres += bno055_set_power_mode(power_mode);

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
************************* END DE-INITIALIZATION **********************
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
return comres;
}

#ifdef  BNO055_API
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*
*   The following function is used to map the I2C bus read, write, delay and
*   device address with global structure bno055_t
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 *  By using bno055 the following structure parameter can be accessed
 *  Bus write function pointer: BNO055_WR_FUNC_PTR
 *  Bus read function pointer: BNO055_RD_FUNC_PTR
 *  Delay function pointer: delay_msec
 *  I2C address: dev_addr
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 s8 I2C_routine(void) {

    bno055.bus_write = BNO055_I2C_bus_write;
    bno055.bus_read = BNO055_I2C_bus_read;
    bno055.delay_msec = BNO055_delay_msek;
    bno055.dev_addr = BNO055_I2C_ADDR2;

    return BNO055_ZERO_U8X;
}

/************** I2C buffer length******/

#define I2C_BUFFER_LEN 8
#define I2C0 5
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*
*
*   This is a sample code for read and write the data by using I2C
*   Use either I2C  based on your need
*   The device address defined in the bno055.h file
*
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*  \Brief: The function is used as I2C bus write
 *  \Return : Status of the I2C write
 *  \param dev_addr : The device address of the sensor
 *  \param reg_addr : Address of the first register, will data is going to be written
 *  \param reg_data : It is a value hold in the array,
 *      will be used for write the value into the register
 *  \param cnt : The no of byte of data to be write
 */
s8 BNO055_I2C_bus_write(u8 dev_addr, u8 reg_addr, u8 *reg_data, u8 cnt)
{
    s32 iError = BNO055_ZERO_U8X;
    u8 array[I2C_BUFFER_LEN];
    u8 stringpos = BNO055_ZERO_U8X;
    array[BNO055_ZERO_U8X;] = reg_addr;
    for (stringpos = BNO055_ZERO_U8X; stringpos < cnt; stringpos++) {
        array[stringpos + BNO055_ONE_U8X] = *(reg_data + stringpos);
    }
    /*
    * Please take the below function as your reference for
    * write the data using I2C communication
    * "IERROR = I2C_WRITE_STRING(DEV_ADDR, ARRAY, CNT+1)"
    * add your I2C write function here
    * iError is an return value of I2C read function
    * Please select your valid return value
    * In the driver SUCCESS defined as 0
    * and FAILURE defined as -1
    * Note :
    * This is a full duplex operation,
    * The first read data is discarded, for that extra write operation
    * have to be initiated. For that cnt+1 operation done in the I2C write string function
    * For more information please refer data sheet SPI communication:
    */
    return (s8)iError;
}

 /* \Brief: The function is used as I2C bus read
 *  \Return : Status of the I2C read
 *  \param dev_addr : The device address of the sensor
 *  \param reg_addr : Address of the first register, will data is going to be read
 *  \param reg_data : This data read from the sensor, which is hold in an array
 *  \param cnt : The no of byte of data to be read
 */
s8 BNO055_I2C_bus_read(u8 dev_addr, u8 reg_addr, u8 *reg_data, u8 cnt)
{
    s32 iError = BNO055_ZERO_U8X;
    u8 array[I2C_BUFFER_LEN] = {BNO055_ZERO_U8X;};
    u8 stringpos = BNO055_ZERO_U8X;
    array[BNO055_ZERO_U8X;] = reg_addr;
    /* Please take the below function as your reference
     * for read the data using I2C communication
     * add your I2C rad function here.
     * "IERROR = I2C_WRITE_READ_STRING(DEV_ADDR, ARRAY, ARRAY, 1, CNT)"
     * iError is an return value of SPI write function
     * Please select your valid return value
     * In the driver SUCCESS defined as 0
     * and FAILURE defined as -1
     */
    for (stringpos = BNO055_ZERO_U8X; stringpos < cnt; stringpos++) {
        *(reg_data + stringpos) = array[stringpos];
    }
    return (s8)iError;
}

#endif
```

Of course I get error messages when I try to compile:

> main.c(108): error:  #268: declaration may not appear after executable statement in block     uint8_t data = I2C_ReceiveData(I2Cx);
>
> main.c(124): error:  #268: declaration may not appear after executable
>   statement in block    uint8_t data = I2C_ReceiveData(I2Cx);
>
> main.c(140): error:  #268: declaration may not appear after executable
>   statement in block    uint8_t received_data(2);
>
> main.c(140): warning:  #550-D: variable "received_data" was set but
>   never used    uint8_t received_data(2);
>
> main.c(207): error:  #20: identifier "comres" is undefined    comres =
>   bno055_init(&bno055);
>
> main.c(207): error:  #20: identifier "bno055" is undefined    comres =
>   bno055_init(&bno055);
>
> main.c(215): error:  #20: identifier "power_mode" is undefined
>     power_mode = POWER_MODE_NORMAL; /* set the power mode as NORMAL*/
>
> main.c(220): warning:  #9-D: nested comment is not allowed
>   /************************* START READ RAW SENSOR DATA****************/
>
> main.c(255): error:  #20: identifier "d_linear_accel_datax" is
>   undefined     comres +=
>   bno055_convert_double_linear_accel_x_msq(&d_linear_accel_datax);
>
> main.c(256): error:  #20: identifier "d_linear_accel_datay" is
>   undefined     comres +=
>   bno055_convert_double_linear_accel_y_msq(&d_linear_accel_datay);
>
> main.c(257): error:  #20: identifier "d_linear_accel_dataz" is
>   undefined     comres +=
>   bno055_convert_double_linear_accel_z_msq(&d_linear_accel_dataz);
>
> main.c(258): error:  #20: identifier "d_linear_accel_xyz" is undefined
>     comres +=
>   bno055_convert_double_linear_accel_xyz_msq(&d_linear_accel_xyz);
>
> main.c(375): warning:  #1-D: last line of file ends without a newline
>
> ## endif

The 'BNO055 sensor' has buit in sensor fusion algorithms (blends accelerometer, magnetometer and gyroscope data into stable three-axis orientation output). So it can output the data that I need. I would like to receive 'X, Y and Z Linear acceleration data as m/s2' and print it out on the Computer screen. I don't know if it is even possible to print out the data on my PC screen, since I connected the Discovery Board via USB to my computer. If it is not possible, then maybe it's possible to print it out on the Discovery Board's built in LCD Display.

Any help to clarify my concern would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: tl;dr, but : Liquid Crystal **Display** display? Provide a [mcve]. SO is no consulting site. Do you have a **specific** problem?

Comment: Compilation errors usually have litle to do with the detail of the application itself - they are just coding errors.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is complaining that the function call

```
init_I2C1();
```

preceeds the declaration

```
uint8_t received_data[2];
```

Some compilers allow this, others (such as yours) must have all variables declared before any executable code in a function.

The second error is of the same type

```
uint8_t data = I2C_ReceiveData(I2Cx);
```

but is more complicated because you are defining the variable and setting its value with executable code. You should separate the two

```
uint8_t data;
// ... more code
data = I2C_ReceiveData(I2Cx);
```

I won't go through them all, most are self-explanatory like `"nested comments not allowed"`.

Comment: Thank you, that was pretty helpful, but I still have trouble figuring out how to define the identifiers correctly

Comment: The next error type is `comres` undefined. It sums the value of some functions, if they are status bits, that would be bad, since if the same status bit is added twice it will move to the next bit. But `comres` might count (un)successful calls: it is undocumented. It is returned by `s32 bno055_data_readout_template(void)` so `s32 comres;` should be defined but isn't locally. You would have to look up the functions called to see what their return values mean. May I suggest you build your project piece by piece, rather than trying to force a whole example to work?

Comment: How can I look up the functions called to see what their return value mein? What do I have to look for and where?

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning on writing a STM32 Discovery port for this IMU in the coming weeks. Until then, I recommend starting with the Arduino example provided by Adafruit and start replacing the Arduino I2C calls with the appropriate STM32 Discovery I2C calls. On the other hand, if you don't need to use the Discovery board and just want the IMU working with a micro-controller, I'd recommend just using the Arduino. Sample projects and libraries already exist here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BNO055